# What is the function of ちょうだい in 読んでちょうだい?

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

What is the function of ちょうだい after 読んで?

I am not quite sure, but I think I saw this subsidiary verb a couple of times in this fixed form and never in another conjugation.

Answer (score 4):

ちょうだい is another way of making a request. It can be replaced by (or replace) ください. E.g.

> 早く来てください
> 早く来てちょうだい
>
> 読んでください
> 読んでちょうだい

The relevant entry from [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A0%82%E6%88%B4-328222#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) (J-J dictionary) is

> ⑤
> 動詞の連用形に助詞「て」の付いた形や，動詞の未然形に「ないで」の付いた形に接続して，補助動詞の命令形のように用いて，親しみの気持ちをこめて相手に求める意を表す。**…てください。** 「この本を見せて－」 「ここにすわらないで－」 〔女性語や幼児語として用いられることが多い〕
> <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

(It also already says in the dictionary entry, but) ちょうだい suggests a more intimate/familiar relationship.

Just to be clear, the use of ちょうだい has nothing to do with 読む (only with the て-form).